# List of files in assets folder and its subfolders

Tags: android, assets, android-assets, android-assetmanager

I have some folders with HTML files in the "assets" folder in my Android project. I need to show these HTML files from assets' sub-folders in a list. I already wrote some code about making this list.

```
lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
// Insert array in ListView

// In the next row I need to insert an array of strings of file names
// so please, tell me, how to get this array

lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filel));
lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
// onclick items in ListView:
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        //Clicked item position
        String itemname = new Integer(position).toString();  
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(DrugList.this, Web.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        //I don't know what it's doing here
        b.putString("defStrID", itemname); 
        intent.putExtras(b);
        //start Intent
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
private boolean listAssetFiles(String path) {

    String [] list;
    try {
        list = getAssets().list(path);
        if (list.length > 0) {
            // This is a folder
            for (String file : list) {
                if (!listAssetFiles(path + "/" + file))
                    return false;
                else {
                    // This is a file
                    // TODO: add file name to an array list
                }
            }
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true; 
}
```

Call the listAssetFiles with the root folder name of your asset folder.

```
    listAssetFiles("root_folder_name_in_assets");
```

If the root folder is the asset folder then call it with

```
    listAssetFiles("");
```

Comment: if you are doing this from an activity or service, then mContext = getApplicationContext(); or mContext = ActivityName.this; Also you can discard it.

Comment: Use StringBuilder do not concatenate String in java

Comment: will assume empty subdirs to be files

Comment: true, but why would one put empty folder in assets?

Comment: @Motasharred : Its been long now...But the else is missing a } in the above snippet

Comment: @Motasharred your solution didn't run subfolders when path="", you'll need a "/" only when path!=""

Comment: Excellent! Worked for me.

Comment: I want to list all images of /assets/images/wallpapers/ directory and store them in a List type variable to use further, how can i do? Any suggestion for flutter?

Answer (score 27):

try this it will work in your case

```
f = getAssets().list("");
for(String f1 : f){
    Log.v("names",f1);
}
```

> The above snippet will show the contents of the asset root.

For example... if below is the asset structure..

```
assets
 |__Dir1
 |__Dir2
 |__File1
```

Snippet's output will be ....
Dir1 Dir2 File1

> If you need the contents of the Directory Dir1

Pass the name of Directory in the list function.

```
  f = getAssets().list("Dir1");
```

Comment: I edited this code, because Eclipse showing errors.

`String[] f = null;
  try {
   f = getAssets().list("");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
         for(String f1:f){
             Log.v("names",f1);
         } ` to this

Comment: And as result - emulator shows me 4 items list: drugs, images, sounds, webkit

Comment: Ya it shows that..but passing the name of youtlr directory inside asset can help you get rid of it pass inside the bracket your parent folder and all its content  will be listed......like getAssets().list("drugs");

Comment: You need to repeat the same process for gwtting the files in every folder inside your assets folder...instead make an array of string having the folder names and keep passing them insidethe list function

Answer (score 3):

Hope This Help:

following code will copy all the folder and it's content and content of sub folder to sdcard location:

```
 private void getAssetAppFolder(String dir) throws Exception{

    {
        File f = new File(sdcardLocation + "/" + dir);
        if (!f.exists() || !f.isDirectory())
            f.mkdirs();
    }
     AssetManager am=getAssets();

     String [] aplist=am.list(dir);

     for(String strf:aplist){
        try{
             InputStream is=am.open(dir+"/"+strf);
             copyToDisk(dir,strf,is);
         }catch(Exception ex){


            getAssetAppFolder(dir+"/"+strf);
         }
     }



 }


 public void copyToDisk(String dir,String name,InputStream is) throws IOException{
     int size;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(sdcardLocation +"/"+dir+"/" +name);
        BufferedOutputStream bufferOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fout, buffer.length);

        while ((size = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            bufferOut.write(buffer, 0, size);
        }
        bufferOut.flush();
        bufferOut.close();
        is.close();
        fout.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to my problem that I found out working 100% listing all directories and files even sub-directories and files in subdirectories.

Note: In my case

1. Filenames had a . in them. i.e. .htm .txt etc
2. Directorynames did not have any . in them.

   ```
   listAssetFiles2(path); // <<-- Call function where required


   //function to list files and directories
   public void listAssetFiles2 (String path){
   String [] list;

   try {
       list = getAssets().list(path);
       if(list.length > 0){
           for(String file : list){
               System.out.println("File path = "+file);

               if(file.indexOf(".") < 0) { // <<-- check if filename has a . then it is a file - hopefully directory names dont have . 
                   System.out.println("This is a folder = "+path+"/"+file);
                   listAssetFiles2(file); // <<-- To get subdirectory files and directories list and check 
               }else{
                   System.out.println("This is a file = "+path+"/"+file);
               }
           }

       }else{
           System.out.println("Failed Path = "+path);
           System.out.println("Check path again.");
       }
   }catch(IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }//now completed
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think that this is best that check file is dir or not, altarnative try,catch!

```
 public static  List<String> listAssetFiles(Context c,String rootPath) {
    List<String> files =new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String [] Paths = c.getAssets().list(rootPath);
        if (Paths.length > 0) {
            // This is a folder
            for (String file : Paths) {
                String path = rootPath + "/" + file;
                if (new File(path).isDirectory())
                    files.addAll(listAssetFiles(c,path));
                else files.add(path);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return files;
}
```

Comment: instead of `if (new File(path).isDirectory())`, use `if (c.getAssets().list(path).length > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @Kammaar answer. This kotlin code scans the file tree for the leafs:

```
private fun listAssetFiles(path: String, context: Context): List<String> {
    val result = ArrayList<String>()
    context.assets.list(path).forEach { file ->
        val innerFiles = listAssetFiles("$path/$file", context)
        if (!innerFiles.isEmpty()) {
            result.addAll(innerFiles)
        } else {
            // it can be an empty folder or file you don't like, you can check it here
            result.add("$path/$file")
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This method return file names in a directory in Assets folder**

```
 private fun getListOfFilesFromAsset(path: String, context: Context): ArrayList<String> {
            val listOfAudioFiles = ArrayList<String>()
            context.assets.list(path)?.forEach { file ->
                val innerFiles = getListOfFilesFromAsset("$path/$file", context)
                if (innerFiles.isNotEmpty()) {
                    listOfAudioFiles.addAll(innerFiles)
                } else {
                    // it can be an empty folder or file you don't like, you can check it here
                    listOfAudioFiles.add("$path/$file")
                }
            }
            return listOfAudioFiles
        }
```

For example you want to load music file path from sound folder

[image]

You can fetch all sound like this:

```
  private const val SOUND_DIRECTORY = "sound"


   fun fetchSongsFromAssets(context: Context): ArrayList<String> {
        return getListOfFilesFromAsset(SOUND_DIRECTORY, context)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] getDirectoryFilesRecursive(String path)
{
    ArrayList<String> result  = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        String[] files = Storage.AssetMgr.list(path);
        for(String file : files)
        {
            String filename = path + (path.isEmpty() ? "" : "/") + file;
            String[] tmp = Storage.AssetMgr.list(filename);
            if(tmp.length!=0) {
                result.addAll(Arrays.asList(getDirectoryFilesRecursive(filename)));
            }
            else {
                result.add(filename);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Native.err("Failed to get asset file list: " + e);
    }
    Object[] objectList = result.toArray();
    return Arrays.copyOf(objectList,objectList.length,String[].class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of @*Kammaar*'s answer, in **Kotlin** [recursive]

```
fun listAssetFiles(
    context: Context,
    path: String,
    dirCallback: ((dirPath: String) -> Unit)? = null,
    fileCallback: (filePath: String) -> Unit,
): Boolean {
    try {
        context.assets.list(path)?.also { files ->
            if (files.isNotEmpty()) {
                for (file in files) {
                    val relativePath = if (path.isEmpty()) file else "$path${File.separatorChar}$file"
                    if (!listAssetFiles(context, relativePath, dirCallback,fileCallback))
                        fileCallback.invoke(relativePath) else dirCallback?.invoke( relativePath)
                }
            } else return false
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {return false}
    return true
}
```

How to use :

```
    listAssetFiles(getApplication(), ""){Log.e("TAG", "File found ->  $it")}
```

Another sample, for retrieving separated list of files and folders:

```
    val fileList = mutableListOf<String>()
    val folderList = mutableListOf<String>()
    listAssetFiles(
        context = getApplication(),
        path = "sample_folder",
        dirCallback = {folderList.add(it)},
        fileCallback = {fileList.add(it)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Kotlin:

```kotlin
val assetManager = context.resources.assets
assetManager
    .list("myDirectoryNameInAssetsFolder")
    .also { Log.i("Meow", "Detected files: ${it?.joinToString()}") }
    ?.map { "myDirectoryNameInAssetsFolder/$it" }
    ?.map(assetManager::open)
    ?.map { it.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText) }
    ?.also { Log.i("Meow", "Text of each file:") }
    ?.forEach { fileText -> Log.i("Meow", fileText) }
    ?: error("Could not access/read files in assets folder")
```