# how to print all file name present in assest folder .?

Tags: android

I have assest in which there are subfolder and files in this way ..

As show in image ..assest->www ->js or cs folder..then files

```
assest
 |
 |__www
     |
     |___js
     |    |
     |    |__a.js
     |
     |____cs
     |     |
     |     |__a.css
     |
     |____index.html
```

I need to print all files name ..can we print that files name

I make this function but not work ..

```
package com.mobilecem.atms;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class GlobalFunction {
    public static boolean listAssetFiles(String path,Context context) {

        String [] list;
        try {


            list = context.getAssets().list(path);
            if (list.length > 0) {
                // This is a folder
                for (String file : list) {
                    if (!listAssetFiles(path + "/" + file, context))
                        return false;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("File Name", "file present");
                // This is a file
                // TODO: add file name to an array list
        } 

        }catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true; 
    }

}
```

call like that

```
GlobalFunction.listAssetFiles("", aaa.this);
```

**Result :**
list have : index.html , a.js, a css

Comment

Comment: use AssetManager.list(String path) to get all files in given path

Comment: can we don't make a generic function mean it give all files name in assest folder

Comment: i didn't get that can you please explain

Comment: @saleeh93 I just want all files name which is present in assest folder in an array.As I said in my assest folder there is www folder then there is js and cs folder inside folders that there is files name a.js and a.css.but in www there is on html file .i need to print the file

Comment: I need to get all file name which present in folder

Comment: just file name not folders ..?
that's what you are looking for..?

Comment: if folder name possible .then it also good..but file name is necessary..can we get that that information which file is inside which folder ..?mean like a.cs is inside cs folder.and a.js in js folder.and aa.html in www folder

Comment: Yea we could give me a moment let me play with that and get you back

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of files in assets folder and its subfolders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234529/list-of-files-in-assets-folder-and-its-subfolders)

Comment: @UmerKiani I already use that but I am not get list of subfolder and files.Please check my Question already use same function

Comment: how you call this function ?

Comment: Testing and Posting a solution with complete working solution

Comment: @UmerKiani how you call this function ?

Comment: Just Simply call it from where you want to show your assets file , like on button click or onCreate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go 
You will have all files and its sub folders details in files List
[image]
Check it out

```
List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

public boolean listAssetFiles(String path, Context context) {


    String[] list;
    try {


        list = context.getAssets().list(path);
        if (list.length > 0) {
            // This is a folder
            for (String file : list) {
                String root = TextUtils.isEmpty(path) ? "" : path + "/";
                String fullpath = root + file;
                files.add(fullpath);
                if (!listAssetFiles(root + file, context))
                    return false;
            }
        } else {

            // This is a file
            // TODO: add file name to an array list
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: let me check wait for second

Comment: how you call this function ?

Comment: what is path parameter ?

Comment: listAssetFiles("", this); use that

Comment: Its just showing concept of working 
you need to modify as your logic of use

Comment: why all give downvoted I also use same code .but have few issue ,,that why i asked

Comment: What is your issue..?

Answer (score 0):

This is fully woriking and showing folder names ive just tested it

```
    private void listFiles(String dirFrom) throws IOException {
    Resources res = getResources(); // if you are in an activity
    AssetManager am = res.getAssets();
    String[] fileList = am.list(dirFrom);
    ArrayList<Drawable> dList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (fileList != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {

            Log.d("FOLDER", fileList[i]);




    }
}
```

Call the listAssetFiles with the root folder name of your asset folder.

```
listAssetFiles("root_folder_name_in_assets");
```

If the root folder is the asset folder then call it with

```
    listAssetFiles("");
```