# Read raw folder content

Tags: android, file, uri

I wolud like to read entire raw project folder content (that contains some .mp3 files). This is how i try to read folder content:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/");
    File file = new File(uri.getPath());
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        Log.i("ADASDAS", files[i].getName());
    }
```

But i obtain a NullPointerException on files object. What's wrong?
The exception is on files.length call.

Comment: Put you mp3 file in assets and list it as here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16235429/1173794

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong?

Pretty much everything:

- a `Uri` is not a `File`, so you cannot pass `getPath()` to `File` and expect it to work
- resources are not files on the device, but rather are entries in an APK file, and so you cannot iterate over them with `File` objects
- the `android.resource` `Uri` structure points to resources, not types of resources (e.g., a specific `raw` resource)

There really isn't a great way to iterate over raw resources. The best not-great way is to use Java reflection to iterate over all `R.raw` fields.