# getting assets not get the files of assets

Tags: android, file, search, assets

I have a project in Android Studio with a lot of libraries. The main project has an assets folder (which contains two folders) and the libraries don't have any assets folders.

I have this code:

```
public static final Pattern LENGUAJES = Pattern.compile("html-(.+)");

public static List<String> getLenguajesHelp(Context oContext) {
    ArrayList<String> oLens = new ArrayList<String>();
    AssetManager assetManager = oContext.getAssets();
    try {
        String[] oFiles = assetManager.list("");
        for (int i = 0; i < oFiles.length; i++) {
            Log.v("probandoElMatcher", oFiles[i]);
            Matcher oMat = LENGUAJES.matcher(oFiles[i]);
            if (oMat.find()) {
                oLens.add(oMat.group(1));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException oEx) {
        oEx.printStackTrace();
    }
    return oLens;
}
```

The `Context` is from the main project (in the assets folder I have a folder named html-es, the idea is that the method matches with that folder) but the method `getAssets.list()` returns a list of files that I don't have in the assets folder, the most of them are `.pak` files. What would be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate : [List of files in assets folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234529/list-of-files-in-assets-folder-and-its-subfolders)

Comment: the problem is that the the folder i want to read is en the root and the getAssets.list does not return that folder. but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i has a lot of flavors, when there are flavors the assets folder must be inside of the main folder (or the specific flavor folder), but i don't know why the get assets returns the .pak files (know returns the .pak files and my files)