# get assets path in File to read multiple files

Tags: android, file, assets

I have multiple .epub file in assets, I want that all .epub file in `listFile`. In my old code i use external storage file path, for getting .epub files, like this

```
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Files" );

File listFile[] = myFile.listFiles();
if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

        if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".epub")) {

            myNewBookModels = new NewBookModels();
            Log.i(TAG, "getEpubFilesFromFileManager: " + ".." + listFile[i].getName());

            myNewBookModels.setBookName(listFile[i].getName().toString());
            myNewBookModels.setBookPath(listFile[i].getPath().toString());
            myNewBookModels.setBitmap(bookLoaded(listFile[i].getName().toString()));
            arrayList.add(myNewBookModels);
        }
    }
}
```

but i want that .epub files from assets folder. How can i do this?

I also want this field from that .epub file

1) Name

2) Path

3) Bitmap (cover page Image)

It is compulsory for me. This can only possible in `File` but i want assets .epub file in `File`

Answer (score 1):

You can access Asset folder using this path - **"file:///android_asset/files"**

OR

```
//Directory or File name
dirForm = "files";  
private void listFiles(String dirFrom) {
        Resources res = getResources(); //if you are in an activity
        AssetManager am = res.getAssets();
        String fileList[] = am.list(dirFrom);

            if (fileList != null)
            {   
                for ( int i = 0;i<fileList.length;i++)
                {
                     File file = new File(fileList[i]);
                     if ((file.getName()).endsWith(".epub")) {

                      Log.i(TAG, "getEpubFilesFromFileManager: " + ".." + file.getName() +"Path"+ file.getPath());
                     }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: In this `fileList[i].getName()` i did't get `getName()`, because fileList[] is string array

Comment: Do directly fileList[i].endsWith(".epub") and skip .getName().
Because fileList array contains file name.

Comment: but i want that name

Comment: You mean to say, you want file Name & file path?

Comment: Try updated Code now. You have to make File object from file name. Hope it works for you.

Comment: its working, but i want list of `File` first then Name, Path and Bitmap, because when i use your code every time Bitmap image is same for all

Answer (score 0):

If your files are in asset folder then it will always be a fixed path. so you can give a hard coded path in string.

Comment: can you please explain in details.

Comment: I meant that when your files were in external storage then they may have variable path. In that case you need to get the path at runtime. But now when your files are in android's asset folder then it will always be fixed in all devices. So you don't need to get path at run time. You can just give a hard coded path. & a typical Android Studio project, you will have an app/ module, with a main/ sourceset (app/src/main/ off of the project root), and so your primary assets would go in app/src/main/assets/. and for names: String[] listOfFileName = getContext().getAssets().list("your/path");

Comment: String[] listOfFileName = getContext().getAssets().list("your/path/inside/asset");

Comment: What else you need? path and name is there and bitmap: you are already getting from name

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) class & then you can [Read files from Assets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16235429/1371792) Folder.