# load file from asset whit subfolders

Tags: android, assets, subdirectory

I have some problems while loading the file from the asset folder.
I wrote a code to load a txt file into a textview and everything works good.
If I try to put some order inside my txt file. I decided to put those files in subfolders in alphabetic order, because I have 800 text files. In this way my code is wrong. Is there a method to maintain the subfolders and load the file whitout specify where they are??
Thanks a lot

Comment: you should post your code and your log cat.

Comment: this thread will show you how to list the subfolders/files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234529/list-of-files-in-assets-folder-and-its-subfolders. this may help you