# How to determine Item in asset folder is a File or a Directory?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-assets

I put some items in my asset folder.
Here as below :

|Asset

|_ONE

|_CAT.JPEG

I want to determine is "ONE" is a Directory, and "CAT.JPEG" is a file.

I Tried with something like below:

```
        AssetManager _assetManager = Assets;
        string[] _files = null;
        try
        {
            _files = _assetManager.List("");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.Error("Get All Child", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
        }
        string _rootAssetFolder = "file:///android_asset/";
        foreach(string _filename in _files)
        {
            string _sourcePathFull = _rootAssetFolder+ _filename;
            Java.IO.File _target = new Java.IO.File(_sourcePathFull);
            if(_target.IsDirectory)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IS DIRECTORY");
            }
            else if(_target.IsFile)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IS FILE");
            }
            else
            {
               Console.WriteLine("UNRECOGNIZE");
            }
        }
```

But I always get UNRECOGNIZE

Comment: I found this, hope i'll help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16235429/10159898

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_isfile.htm
By the way what you have set in _sourcePathFull?